# Rails - existing development Postgres database on local machine to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

I have developed a `Rails 3.2.13` app with `PostgreSQL` development database on my Windows7 machine.  I was able to push my app to heroku with success.  However, now I'm stuck at the process of migrating the existing data to Heroku.

I have tried following along the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import_push_to_heroku) by Heroku, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Installed the PG Backups heroku addon
2. Created a dump file for my development database with the command  `pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user myapp_development > myapp_development.dump`
3. Uploaded the dump file to AWS S3

At this point, I am not sure how to proceed, to restore the dump file and turn it to a production database in Heroku.  Can anyone please help?

P.S. 
I also have tried the `heroku db:push` command, but it gave the following error:

> Failed to connect to database:   Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError:
>   cannot load such file -- pg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) On S3, you need to set your dump file to be publicly readable.

Within the S3 bucket, right-click the dump file you uploaded, and click 'Make Public'

Now, when you click the 'Properties' button (top-right area) for that file, you will see a 'Link' value. This means the file is now accessible from outside, including by Heroku.

b) You will need to run a command like this to restore this pg dump to your heroku database:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://your.s3.domain.here.s3-us-xxxx-xx.amazonaws.com/myapp_development.dump' --app your-heroku-app-name
```

Notes:

- To run the 'heroku' command, you'll need to install the heroku toolbelt.
- Note that the http URL in step (b) will be the same public URL as the one you saw in 'Properties' in step (a) above.
- DATABASE is a heroku keyword for this command, and should be typed out as is. It equates to the DATABASE_URL config setting you see when you run:

`$ heroku config --app your-heroku-app-name`

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the uploaded dump file on S3, you need to tell pgbackups to load up that dump.

Try something like this:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path/to/myapp_development.dump'
```

I found that command here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

**Edit:**

`DATABASE_URL` should work verbatim. But if you would like to specify the database, you can use `heroku pg:info` to find out the name of your database.

For me, `heroku pg:info` prints:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Basic
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.1.9
Created:     2013-03-06 17:21 UTC
Data Size:   9.5 MB
Tables:      9
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

So, in my case I would use:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path/to/myapp_development.dump'
```

Comment: that's the same guide that I read, but what I don't understand is what to put in "DATABASE" (that's a placeholder right?), and how I can get the path to the S3 dump file (i literally just signed up for aws, so please excuse the ignorance)

Comment: OH, it should probably work to put `DATABASE_URL` in the place of "DATABASE". However, you might also try running `heroku pg:info` and using the database name at the top. I'll edit the answer to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all gems are install on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby

gem install heroku taps sequel

sudo gem install tabs

sudo heroku db:push
```

OR

```
sudo heroku db:push –config herokuServerName
```

If still problem. Use below command

```
heroku db:pull postgres://root:@localhost/db_name
```

Else

```
sudo heroku db:pull --confirm herokuDomanName postgres://userName:@localhost/Locadatabase
```

root will be database user name and db_name is database name.

Good Luck.........!!